# Langrange polinomial interpolation with value of derivatives?

Tags: interpolation, lagrange-interpolation

I have an interpolation problem to be solved with Lagrange polinomials. In the data set $(x_i,y_i)$ points are given, also the value of the $f'(x_1)$. How can I proceed with the interpolation?

Comment: You should use [Hermite interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_interpolation)

Comment: @caverac Thank you! But what if they give me only one derivative and the rest of data points?

Comment: Do they give you both the derivative and the value of the function at one location? If that is the case, Hermite interpolation will work for you